# Angular UI - Datepicker doesnt work until selected

Tags: angularjs

When using the Angular UI datepicker in the edit view of the form, until I change the date of the input box the date is not getting passed through Angular UI.

Eg : If the existing date value is 16-September-2014

If I just POST the data without clicking on the datepicker the value I get in javascript is

'16-September-2014'

But if I first select the datepicker and change the date the final value I get in javascript is

'2014-09-06 00:00:00'

This is library I am using

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your code.I am not sure, but it may solve your problem.
$scope.toDay = new Date();
$scope.date = $scope.toDay;

Now bind $scope.date in your HTML/Jade using ng-model. 
 data-ng-model="date"